How to find names that define a list not in name manager
In an excel cell there is an associated drop down list.  When I look it up I see the following

The data I'm interested in is:
=INDIRECT("Staff_Cat[Staff_Role]")
When I go to Name Manager, I do not see Staff_Cat or Staff_Role.
The drop list rules are enforced, so these names ranges must exists somewhere.
I've been going around in circles because I cannot find where Staff_Cat is defined. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Does dropdown list work? If so, the table name Staff_Cat must be defined. You should see it in the Name Manager. If it is not visible, check and clear the Name Manager filter.

@MGonet cleared filter but they didn't show.

CRTL+ G is the goto shortcut. type in the name range and see where it takes you.  It'll throw an error if that range is no longer valid.

It's a table called Staff_Cat you're interested in the data =Staff_Cat or where it's at?

@P.b. According to Jan, it's a vestige of a previous name that no longer exists.  I don't know how excel holds the memory...

@SeanJ it doesn't. By using INDIRECT it refers to a name. If it doesn't exist it still refers to that name, since INDIRECT is.. indirectly referring to a range, not directly.
